# C macro functions - how to recognize a substring containing arg?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to define the following macro functions:

```
#define TEST_INSTRUCTIONS_INPUT(name) const InstructionArray name =
#define TEST_INSTRUCTIONS_SIZE(name) const uint16_t name_size = sizeof(name) / sizeof(name[0]);
```

The first works, but the second does not (`name` is not replaced).

In general it seems `F(x) x_name` will not replace `x`, so `F(test)` -> `x_name`, rather than `test_name`

My guess is the C preprocessor:

- Does not recognize macro args if they're a substring of what it considers a 'word'
- Does not consider `_` as a valid delimeter between 'words'

Is there a way around this to get what I want? (Function declerations with "decorated" names).

Thanks.

Comment: Try using the ## "operator"

Comment: [from the GNU C Preprocessor docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation), which hopefully make it unnecessary to guess.

Comment: `_` is a valid character for identifiers. It does not separate "words".

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way around this to get what I want?

Yes, concatenate the tokens. This is what `##` is for.

```
#define TEST_INSTRUCTIONS_SIZE(name) const uint16_t name##_size = ...
```